# csv file could not import to datagrid in vb.net import

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
        Dim strFileName As String
        Dim excelconstring As String
        'Dim excelcon As New OleDbConnection
        Dim excelcon As New OdbcConnection
        Button5.Enabled = False
        fd.Title = "Open File Dialog"
        fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\chrome\allotment\2022\feb 2022"
        fd.Filter = "Excel file (*.xls)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        fd.FilterIndex = 3
        fd.RestoreDirectory = True

        If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            strFileName = fd.FileName
           
            Dim fileext As String = Path.GetExtension(strFileName)




            If fileext = ".csv" Then


                '------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                Dim csvFileFolder As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName)
                Dim csvFileName As String = Path.GetFileName(strFileName)
                Dim connString As String = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" _
                    & csvFileFolder & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"""

                Dim conn As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(connString)

                'Open a data adapter, specifying the file name to load
                Dim daa As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & csvFileName & "]", conn)
                'Then fill a data table, which can be bound to a grid
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                daa.Fill(dt)

                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt








            ElseIf fileext = ".xls " OrElse fileext = ".XLS" OrElse fileext = ".xlsx" Then




                '-----------------------------------------------------------------excel file--------------------------------------------------------------------------'
                excelconstring = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & strFileName & ""
                excelcon = New OdbcConnection(excelconstring)
                excelcon.Open()

                Dim da As New OdbcDataAdapter("select * from [STOCK_ISSUE_REGISTER_REPORT$]", excelcon)
                Dim ds As New DataSet

                da.Fill(ds)


                DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)


            End If
        End If
```

This code is working in developing machine which have windows 32 bit Os.when i publish and installed in wndows  7 64bit machine,only excel file is imported, CSv file could not be imported. when i install in windows 10 machine,both excel and csv file could not be installed. whats wrong with this code. I have published my projects as ANYCPU mode and iatalled interop and accessdatabaseengine in all machines.

Comment: As per your other question on this, not only do you need to ensure you build your app with the correct 32/64 bit set up, but you also need to ensure the target machines have the correct/expected access database engine installed.  This is why I suggested you look at any of the many 3rd party tools you can add to your project via nugets to preform your csv file parsing and thus eliminate this complication

Comment: Solved it. Thank you